# RustのStringは「usize」なのか？

Tags: rust

とあるネットワーク系プログラムをRustで書いています。そこで`String`型が何故か`usize`として認識されてしまっているので質問させていただきます。かなりのコード量な上、検索に引っかかると厄介な個人的事情もありますので、必要な部分のみを掲載させていただきます。予めご了承ください。

### 問題の箇所

```
    let &ip; let host; let parse_ip; let perse_host;
    let ipx = &ip;

    if cli.value_of("ipaddress").is_none() && cli.value_of("hostname").is_none() {
        println!("{}", HELP);
        std::process::exit(1);
    } else if cli.value_of("ipaddress").is_some() || cli.value_of("hostname").is_none() {
        ip = String::from(cli.value_of("ipaddress").unwrap());  
        parse_ip = ip.parse::<IpAddr>().unwrap();

    } else {     
        host = cli.value_of("hostname").unwrap();
        perse_host = || {
            let hostname: Vec<std::net::IpAddr> = lookup_host(host).unwrap();
            let host_to_ip = hostname[0].clone();
            return host_to_ip;
        };
    }
```

このように条件付きで、入力ホストとIPをそれぞれパース・初期化を行っています、この時点て後述する`let ip`は[E0614](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html)に引っかかったので、例に習い`let ipx = &ip;`としています。

```
    let mut network_node;

    if *ipx.len() <= 3 {
        eprintln!("\x1b[31m[-]\x1b[m CAN NOT PARSE YOUR INPUT INTO IpAddr!");
        std::process::exit(1);
    } else {
        network_node = parse_ip;
    }
        
    if perse_host().is_ipv4() {
        eprintln!("\x1b[31m[-]\x1b[m CAN NOT PARSE YOUR INPUT INTO HOST!");
        std::process::exit(1);
    } else { 
        network_node = perse_host();
    }
```

次がコードの制御部です。先の`ip`の参照を`ipx`に渡したものを、参照外しで逆参照しています。しかしここで、

`` type `usize` cannot be dereferenced ``

と出てしまいます。自分の認識ではString型はコンパイル時にサイズが決定する筈なので、通常ではチェックは通るはずなのですが、現時点まで未解決のままです。

これを解決するにはどのような手段を取ればよいのでしょうか？

### 環境

```
active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.45.0-nightly (56daaf669 2020-06-03)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ご指南通り、アスタリスクを外してみたところ、なにやら「初期化が必要」とのエラーが発生したのですが、これはどう解決すれば良いのでしょうか...nullの代わりにNoneと()を入れてみましたが解決できませんでした... ``borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: ip use of possibly-uninitialized `ip```

コードを省略されているため、意図がわかりづらい部分があるのですが、

```rust
let &ip;
let ipx = &ip;
```

は本来はip変数に何かString型の値を入れるコード (仮に `get_ip()` とします) が存在するという仮定で回答します。

ipがString型なのであればString型の値で初期化する必要があります。

変数宣言時に値を入れる場合。

```rust
let ip: String = get_ip();
println!("{}", ip);
```

値の取得にあたって条件分岐などがあり、まず空文字で初期化する場合。

```rust
let mut ip: String = "".to_string()
if is_something() {
  ip = get_ip();
}
println!("{}", ip);
```

Noneで初期化する場合はOption型にする必要があります。

```rust
let mut ip: Option<String> = None;
if is_something() {
  ip = Some(get_ip());
}
println!("{}", ip.unwrap());
```

Answer (score 3):

問題なのは `*ipx.len() <= 3` の部分ですね。
`*ipx.len()` は、 `*(ipx.len())` と解釈されます。 `ipx.len()` の返り値は `usize` なので、それを参照外ししようとして、エラーになっています。
また、Rustでは `recv.method()` と呼んだ際は辻褄が合うように `*` や `&` が裏で付与されるので、レシーバに `&` や `*` をつけり必要性は基本的にはありません （参考： [->演算子はどこに行ったの？](https://doc.rust-jp.rs/book/second-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#a-%E6%BC%94%E7%AE%97%E5%AD%90%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%93%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE)）。

なので `ipx.len() <= 3` と書き換えたらコンパイルが通らないでしょうか。

Comment: ご指南通り、アスタリスクを外してみたところ、なにやら「初期化が必要」とのエラーが発生したのですが、これはどう解決すれば良いのでしょうか...nullの代わりに`None`と`()`を入れてみましたが解決できませんでした... ``borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `ip` use of possibly-uninitialized `ip```

Comment: @RemoGiazotto エラーメッセージで図示されているかと思いますが、2行目の `let ipx = &ip;` で未初期化の `ip` を参照しているからです。